# JSON returns nil Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to access data on the page https://api.myjson.com/bins/4xi1h
but it returns nil not the data. I have no idea why.

when I replace the URL with some other JSON API, this code returns data.

```
var restUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/4xi1h")!
let jsonUrlData = NSData (contentsOfURL: restUrl)
println(jsonUrlData)


if jsonUrlData != nil{
var dictionary : NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonUrlData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
println(dictionary)}
```

Comment: I can't see where you are trying to parse JSON here?

Comment: The dictionary is correctly populated, see my [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s89/sh/8a3e1d89-f402-4279-b0f3-1759be24a3a3/61f49c7e9adbd1358f4285c3b481715a/deep/0/dfsdsdf.playground.png). I just had to use `as! NSDictionary` instead of `as NSDictionary` (note the `!`). You must have had a different kind of problem, then.

Comment: @ericd That appears to be a Swift 1.2 error, which the OP may or may not be using.

Comment: Here is your problem: `error: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

The connection to MyJSON is not secure; try accessing the API over HTTP instead:

```
var restUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://api.myjson.com/bins/4xi1h")!
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not trust the Playground display. Sometime it just does not display correctly. Verify with your XCode. Anyway, your code is OK, you have just to be sure that the json is a Dictionary but not an Array (it's the case cause I see that the cast is OK in your screenshot).

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast the result appropriately:

```
var dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonUrlData!, 
                 options: .MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
```

Also, please note that your synchronous API call might be appropriate in a quick test but not in an app as it would potentially block the UI.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the problem; it very well could be, but I'd think that if the OP were using Swift 1.2, where the forced downcast is required (it's not in earlier versions), then s/he would have noticed the error given by Xcode and used the suggested auto-fix. Rather, it appears that the API call is unsuccessful, as `jsonUrlData` amounts to `nil`.